# Login and register link not working in Laravel after executing make:auth command

Tags: laravel, scaffolding

I have installed laravel in windows and tried the make:auth command to scaffold basic login,registration views and routes. But when i tried to access the page with the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/login, it displayed the following error "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." I tried searching for the reason. But i didnt get a proper solution yet for the past week. [image: login page after running make:auth command]

Comment: Did you run `php artisan migrate`? Did you go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/register after runnig it?

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` . Do you see route `login`? If not, check the file `routes/web.php`. Do you see `Auth::routes();` in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Run Command:

> php artisan make:auth

And then :

> php artisan serve

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Laravel you are using ?

if the version is below 6, You have to use this command

```
php artisan migrate  
php artisan make:auth
```

if the version is 6 or above, Run this commands

```
php artisan migrate
composer require laravel/ui
npm install
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install && npm run dev
```